# How do I reconnect my project to my existing GitHub repository

Tags: git, github, clone

I am working on an Xcode project with source control. I messed up so I deleted the project from my laptop, and downloaded (ZIP) my own project which I pushed to GitHub earlier. But now this cloned project **is not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git**

Question: How do I reconnect my project to my existing GitHub repository?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest is to:

- clone your GitHub project
- cd in that local clone
- do a `git --work-tree=/path/to/unzip/project diff` to check if your zip has any differences with the version cloned from git hub: if it does, git add and commit. (and by that use `git --work-tree=/path/to/unzip/project add -A .` and then a simple `git commit`, to record the differences from the zip version of the project and the git cloned one)
- resume working with the local clone (which is a git repo)

Comment: is the syntax really `git --work-tree='...' diff`, not `git diff --work-tree='...' ` ?

Comment: @NickVolynkin yes, this isn't a parameter for `diff`, it is a parameter for `git` itself, in order to consider a different path as the current working tree.

Comment: @NickVolynkin you also have the `--git-dir` option. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20115526/6309.

Comment: Oh, understood. Now for "git add and commit". What to add if the repo was just cloned? Files should be copied to the local clone.

Comment: @NickVolynkin the `git add` would use `git --work-tree add` in order to add the content from the zip project to the git repo. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @VonC  (1) Is a _work-tree_ a _branch_ or a _repo_? (2) Does _/path/to/unzip/project_ mean _https://github.com/username/repo.git_ ?

Comment: @abacaba (1) work-tree is a repository state: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/30206960/6309. Here it tells git to consider a folder a being the working tree for the current git repo. So (2):  `/path/to/unzip/project` is *not* a git repo: it is a backup of the project with their files (no git information in it). But the `--work-tree` allows git to consider those files as if they were for the current git repo that you just cloned.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to clone the git repository somewhere, and then copy the `.git` directory from there in to your project folder.

This folder will then become a git repository, and you can do `git status` and all the usual commands to do what you need to do.

There are probably some caveats, but it worked well for me in a situation where moving the project folder would have been difficult.